# Copy data from S3 bucket in one AWS account to S3 bucket in other AWS account with acl permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hello everyone please help out for s3 migration.

I am migrating s3 bucket one account to other s3 bucket aws account with object permission. I have migrated the s3 bucket but I do not migrate the with object permission. so please help me out this.

This is bucket policy in source account.

```
{

  "Version": "2012-10-17",

  "Statement": [

    {

      "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",

      "Effect": "Allow",

      "Principal": {

        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::12345678910:user/abc"

      },

      "Action": [

        "s3:ListBucket",

        "s3:GetObject"

      ],

      "Resource": [

        "arn:aws:s3:::sourceBucketB/*",

        "arn:aws:s3:::sourceBucketB"

      ]

    }

  ]

}
```

And this is policy applied to destination account.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",


"Statement": [


{


            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [


                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"

            ],


            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {

            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::destinationbucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::destinationbucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ] }
```